# Create Point Shapefile Using Excel Table of Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python, sql, excel, arcmap

This should be very simple:
I have an Excel table with pollution detection sites, and their corresponding Latitudes and Longitudes.  I want to create a point shapefile for this table.

I have written a script to create the file, but cannot figure out how to create the points in it:

```
#Creates Observation Site Shapefile

import arcpy
import fileinput
import string
import os
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "F:\GEOG 487B\Project"
env.overwriteOutput = True
outpath = env.workspace
newfc = "sites.shp"
infile = "site_loc.xls"
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfc, "Point")
```

The shapefile is created, but the attribute table is empty.  How can I get ArcMap to recognize my Latutude and Longitude columns?
The table is very simple:
Column A = Site ID#, B = Latitude, C = Longitude

Thanks!!

Comment: This might be a better question for the GIS group.  See this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-python-and-arcpy

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a library which can read/write shape files.  I've used it to read in National Weather Service Shapefiles in the past.

http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/

From the examples on that webpage,  writing points into a shape file looks fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably late, but you can use [Make XY Event Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Make_XY_Event_Layer/00170000006z000000/) and then save the output layer to a shapefile or feature class with e.g. [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Copy_Features/001700000035000000/).
You can also do this without Python by right-clicking your xls sheet in ArcCatalog > Create feature class from XY table.